# header dissapears on js collapse menu

Tags: javascript, menu

I have a collapsible menu that uses easy js and works great but when you click it header disappears. the js works for both menus easy but if i try to change the text in the js so that it appears then it changes them for both drop downs. basicly how do i make it so just the "+" and "-" change but not the "champion" "hanes" text? I also tried putting the "Champion" outside the span but it still changed cause it's in the header and i don't know how to change the js to change just the span instead of the whole header.

```js
$(".header").click(function () {

    $header = $(this);
    //getting the next element
    $content = $header.next();
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
        //execute this after slideToggle is done
        //change text of header based on visibility of content div
        $header.text(function () {
            //change text based on condition
            return $content.is(":visible") ? "-" : "+";
        });
    });

});
```

```css
.collapsemenu {
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.collapsemenu div {
    width:100%;
}
.collapsemenu .header {
    background-color: #0FBAC1;
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.collapsemenu .content {
    display: none;
    padding : 5px;
}
.collapsemenu .content ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapsemenu">
    <div class="header">
      <span>Champion +</span>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">T-Shirts</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tanks</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Polos</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Long Sleeve</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Hoodies</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sweats</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Youth</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /collapsemenu -->

<div class="collapsemenu">
    <div class="header">
      <span>Hanes +</span>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /collapsemenu -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap the + or - sign in a span, and then only call the change on that span.

```js
$(".header").click(function () {

    $header = $(this);
    //getting the next element
    $content = $header.next();
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
        //execute this after slideToggle is done
        //change text of header based on visibility of content div
        $sign = $header.children(".sign");
        $sign.text(function () {
            //change text based on condition
            return $content.is(":visible") ? "-" : "+";
        });
    });

});
```

```css
.collapsemenu {
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.collapsemenu div {
    width:100%;
}
.collapsemenu .header {
    background-color: #0FBAC1;
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.collapsemenu .content {
    display: none;
    padding : 5px;
}
.collapsemenu .content ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapsemenu">
    <div class="header">
      Champion <span class="sign">+</span>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">T-Shirts</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Tanks</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Polos</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Long Sleeve</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Hoodies</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sweats</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Youth</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /collapsemenu -->

<div class="collapsemenu">
    <div class="header">
      Hanes <span class="sign">+</span>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /collapsemenu -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You're wiping out the text of the element. Change your `slideToggle` to:

```
$content.slideToggle(500, function () {
    var currentText = $header.text();

    if ($content.is(":visible")) {
        currentText.replace(/\+{1}$/), '-');
    } else {
        currentText.replace(/\-{1}$/), '+');
    }

    $header.text(currentText);
});
```

Comment: this one added a + and - sign each time instead of replacing them.

Comment: I've edited my answer. You can try the above, though I find it a fragile solution. What it does is replace a `+` or `-` based on a Regular Expression that matches those symbols at the end of the string.